# Array and put the index value to option menu?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using PHP.

I have an array as below.

```
$wupincat = array('','sword','knife','bow');
```

I would like to put this array into a option menu, but I cannot specified the menu `option value`.

My PHP side is:

```
$wupincat = array('','sword','knife','bow');
```

My HTML side:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
  {loop $wupincat $wp}
  <option value="">$wp</option>
  {/loop}
</select>
```

My final output:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
  <option value="">sword</option>
  <option value="">knife</option>
  <option value="">bow</option>
</select>
```

How to specified my `option value` ??

This is what I need:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
  <option value="1">sword</option>
  <option value="2">knife</option>
  <option value="3">bow</option>
</select>
```

How to improve my coding or I miss something?

======
Consolidate all the answers, I has been solve my problem:
Final coding is:
My PHP side:

```
$wupincat = array('','sword','knife','bow');
$arrayfilter = array_filter($wupincat);
foreach($arrayfilter as $key => $value) {
    $crazylist[$key]['title'] = $value;
    $crazylist[$key]['key'] = $key;
}
```

My HTML side:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {loop $crazylist $value}
    <option value="{$value[key]}">{$value[title]}</option>
  {/loop}
</select>
```

Final output (Success!)

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">sword</option>
  <option value="2">knife</option>
  <option value="3">bow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using twig or something? As that HTML is not vanilla HTML or PHP

Comment: How does the loop in your HTML code work? It's not PHP. Is it part of a front-end framework or something?

Comment: Please tell us which Templating Engine you are using

Comment: I use a forum BBS software call `Discuz!X` from China, I am doing some plugin for that, this `loop` coding was I learn from the tutorial from their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using a template engine. So, we need to know what the template engine is. You can either use the vanila PHP code which other guys provided the answer, or use the template engine proper code format.

It could be something like this:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
{loop $wupincat $key => $wp}
  <option value="$key">$wp</option>
{/loop}
</select>
```

Again, to provide the exact code, we need to know the template engine

Comment: OP wants the index as the value

Comment: But at least this guy has noticed that OP is using a template engine and is not suggesting vanilla PHP solutions

Comment: @JimWright. I don't see any request for putting index as value. I don't think downvoting is fair.

Comment: @Mojtaba Under "This is what I need" OP has int's as the value. The ints match up with the array index.

Comment: @JimWright. You are right. I missed that part. So, he has to provide us what the template engine is. Or, use the pure PHP code which you guys provided. I update the answer

Comment: Still a typo. `key` should be `$key`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this way,

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
 <?php 
  $wupincat = array('','sword','knife','bow'); 
  foreach($wupincat as $cc => $name) {
     if($name !=='')
     echo '<option value="' . $cc . '">' . $name . '</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you notice the OP Is using a templating engine and not vanilla PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly ohh yes, I missed that :) may I need to change my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Add this loop between your select:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
<?php 
  foreach ($wupincat as $index => $item) {
    if (empty($item)) { continue; }
    echo '<option value="' . $index . '">' . $item . '</option>';
  } 
?>
</select>
```

Comment: instead of `$wp` it should be an `$item`

Comment: Whoops, it's been a long day, fixed now.

Comment: Did you notice the OP Is using a templating engine and not vanilla PHP

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla PHP you can use the following:

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
<?php ($wupincat as $index => $wp) {
    echo '<option value="' . $index . '">' . $wp . '</option>';
?>
</select>
```

I'm not sure what templating framework you are using, but maybe this works for you?

```
<select name="wcat" id="typeid" class="ps">
{loop $wupincat $index => $wp}
    <option value="$index">$wp</option>
{/loop}
</select>
```

Comment: `index+1` ? Why

Comment: @RiggsFolly I missed that the first element was empty and saw that OP started from 1. Updated.